# Creating a dynamic table in SQL Server with Java Spring

Tags: java, sql-server

I am new in Java. Now I am trying to create a dynamic SQL table in a SQL Server Database from java. I have the table Name in a string, the column names in a ArrayList, and put the same type and length for all columns that I want. My code look like this, but when I run It I obtain this error, I don't know why, because the "query" variable is printing a "correct" Query. I test it writing a static tableName and tColumnNames and worked fine...If someone can help me to resolve it, I really will appreciate it. Thanks

```
private void createNewTable( String tableName, List<String> newTableColumns) throws SQLException {
    
    //ArrayList to string separated by comma
    
    String tColumNames = String.join(",",newTableColumns );
    
    Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
    Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
    String query = "CREATE TABLE "+tableName+"( "+tColumNames+" );";
    System.out.println("Consulta"+query);
    stmt.executeUpdate(query);
    stmt.close();
}
```

"query" is printing this:

> CREATE TABLE Courses(Subject ID VARCHAR(200),Date*
> VARCHAR(200),Effective Date* VARCHAR(200) );

And it is the error

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near
> 'VARCHAR'.    at
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:217)
> at
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1655)
> at
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:885)
> at
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:778)
> at
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7505)
> at
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2445)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Java looks ok but there are syntax errors in your SQL.  Do you have control of the code that generates the value for `newTableColumns`?  That is where your problem is.  Your statement should read something more like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Courses([Subject ID] VARCHAR(200), [Date*] VARCHAR(200), [Effective Date*] VARCHAR(200) );
```

If you have spaces or other T-SQL reserved characters or keywords you need to enclose them in `[]`.

If you don't have control of the value of `newTableColumns` then you will need to parse that string to format it accordingly before or while you generate your SQL statement.